# Fake induction proofs

Tags: induction, recreational-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, big-list, fake-proofs

**Question:** Can you provide an example of a claim where the base case holds but there is a *subtle* flaw in the inductive step that leads to a fake proof of a clearly erroneous result? [Note: Please do not answer with the very common [all horses are the same color](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428151/questions-on-all-horse-are-the-same-color-proof-by-complete-induction) example.]

**Comment:** Sometimes inductive arguments can lead to controversial conclusions, such as the [surprise exam paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97331/surprise-exam-paradox), [Richard's paradox](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RichardsParadox.html) and a host of other paradoxes. However, I am interested in examples of a more mathematical nature (as opposed to linguistic) where the inductive argument is *subtly* flawed and leads to erroneous conclusions.

**Note:** If you provide an answer, please do so in a way similar to how current answers are displayed (gray out the flaw so people can be challenged to discover it).

Comment: I don't remember the erroneous proof of the four-color theorem that was published in the 1890s, but I wonder if that might have been one of these.

Answer (score 85):

**Claim:** $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=0$ for all $n\ge0$.

**Base case:** ($n=0$): $\frac{d}{dx}x^0=\frac{d}{dx}1=0$

**Inductive step:** Assume that $\frac{d}{dx}x^k=0$ for all $k\le n$. Then by the product rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^{n+1}=\frac{d}{dx}(x^n\cdot x^1)=x^n\frac{d}{dx}x^1+\left(\frac{d}{dx}x^n\right)x^1=x^n\cdot0+0\cdot x^1=0.$$

**Flaw:**

> In order for this to be a valid proof, the inductive step must be valid for all $n\ge0$. However, when $n=0$, one can’t use the inductive hypothesis to rewrite $\frac{d}{dx}x^1$ as $0$.

This “spoof” appears in Martin V. Day’s “[An Introduction to Proofs and the Mathematical Vernacular](http://intranet.math.vt.edu/people/day/ProofsBook/).” Day gives its source as Edward J. Barbeau’s “[Mathematical Fallacies, Flaws and Flimflam](http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/mathematical-fallacies-flaws-and-flimflam).”

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Comment: I thought that when OP said "with a correct base step" that meant that the correct *number* for the base step is true as well - in this case, the base step is incorrectly used since we should start instead from $n=1$. In fact, many of the proofs in this thread have  a flaw that is exactly that.

Comment: @Soke Interesting observation. I thought it was pretty clear from the example answers what is desired, but feel free to add a comment in the question body to address what you just commented on.

Comment: @crash It is pretty clear what you meant. I suppose I was just hoping that there would be something that *wasn't* just the wrong number in the base case.

Comment: I would reformulate this as a proof by *strong* induction, i.e.,  assume it's true for all $k\lt n$ and then show ${d\over dx}x^n={d\over dx}(x^k\cdot x^{n-k})=\ldots$.

Answer (score 50):

Here is a "proof" of a famous identity by Ramanujan:
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3{\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\dots}}}}}}=2.$$

**Claim:** Let us prove this more general result for all $n\geq 0$:
$$\sqrt{1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{1+(n+3)\sqrt{\ldots}}}}}=n+1.$$

**Base case:** When $n=0$, we have $\sqrt{1+0\sqrt{\dots}}=0+1$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Assume that the identity holds for some $n$ and let us prove it holds for $n+1$. By squaring both sides we get
$$1+n\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{1+(n+3)\sqrt{\ldots}}}}=n^2+2n+1.$$
Subtracting $1$ and dividing by $n$, we get
$$\sqrt{1+(n+1)\sqrt{1+(n+2)\sqrt{1+(n+3)\sqrt{\ldots}}}}=n+2,$$
which is what we wanted to show. $\blacksquare$

**Flaw:**

> We cannot divide by $n$ because at the very beginning of induction $n=0$. Moreover, one should justify the existence of the infinite nested radical.

**Comment:** This "proof" is funny because, in fact, it gives a correct result!

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Comment: Can this argument be made more rigorous by considering the limit of the two sides as $n$ approaches $0$?  (Just for the first induction step.  After that, the induction step works as stated.)

Comment: @crash Unfortunately after reading through several of these "fake proof" threads, I have become distrustful of the word "divide"!

Comment: @BradyGilg what do you mean exactly? That the proofs are really deceptive or you don't like the topic being considered?

Comment: @crash That I was not fooled by the fake proof because I've been trained through experience to recognize the word "divide" as a red flag.

Comment: Now, if you'd written "Euler" instead of "Ramanujan" and some sort of infinitesimal instead of $0$, I would have thought this *was* his proof.

Comment: @BradyGilg Ah. Yes. That's what I immediately saw to be wrong. There always seems to be something squirrelly going on there. I was marginally stumped at first but then decided to investigate the point of division...then tada.

Comment: Awarding you the bounty because I've never seen this deception before. Even though the problem occurs in division, as most fake proofs do, the flaw is rather subtle. Very nice. +100

Answer (score 44):

**Claim:** $a^n=1$ for all nonnegative integers $n$, whenever $a$ is a nonzero real number.

**Base case:** $a^0=1$ is true by the definition of $a^0$.

**Inductive step:** Assume that $a^m=1$ for all nonnegative integers $m$ with $m\leq k$. Then notice that
$$
a^{k+1}=\frac{a^k\cdot a^k}{a^{k-1}}=\frac{1\cdot 1}{1}=1.
$$

**Flaw:**

> The flaw occurs in the inductive step where we implicitly assume that $k\geq 1$ in order for us to talk about $a^{k-1}$ in the denominator; otherwise, the exponent is not a nonnegative integer, meaning we **cannot** apply the inductive hypothesis. We checked the base case only for $n=0$; thus, we are not justified in assuming that $k\geq 1$ when we try to prove the statement for $k+1$ in the inductive step. It is exactly at $n=1$ that the proposition breaks down.

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Answer (score 25):

Here is one published by Knuth.

**Claim:** $$\underbrace{\frac1{1\cdot2}+\frac1{2\cdot3}+\ldots}_{n\text{ terms}}=\frac32-\frac1n$$

**Base case:** For $n=1$, we have $\frac32-\frac11=\frac1{1\cdot2}$

**Inductive step:** 
$$\left(\frac1{1\cdot2}+\ldots+\frac1{(n-1)\cdot n}\right)+\frac1{n\cdot(n+1)}=\frac32-\frac1n+\frac1{n\cdot(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac32-\frac1n+\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac32-\frac1{n+1}$$

**Flaw:**

> The indexing is wrong. I altered the statement slightly to make it harder to spot.

Comment: It's in _Fundamental Algorithms_, at the very beginning.

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Comment: Can you explain the flaw in more detail, this proof seems genius

Comment: @Milan $\left(\dfrac{1}{1\cdot 2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{(n-1)\cdot n}\right)$ has $n-1$ terms, so according to the inductive hypothesis $\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{1}{n-1}$ should be substituted in place of that sum.

Comment: @pkwssis  I got it in the meantime, its very dirty

Answer (score 15):

**Claim:** For every $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, if $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ with $\max(x,y)=n$, then $x=y$.

**Base case:** Suppose that $n=1$. If $\max(x,y)=1$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then $x=1$ and $y=1$.

**Inductive step:** Let $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Assume that whenever $\max(x,y)=k$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, then $x=y$. Now let $\max(x,y)=k+1$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then $\max(x-1,y-1)=k$. By the inductive hypothesis, $x-1=y-1$. It follows that $x=y$, completing the inductive step.

**Flaw:**

> The flaw occurs when applying the inductive hypothesis to look at $\max(x-1,y-1)$. Even though $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, $x-1$ and $y-1$ do not necessarily need to be (for example, one or even both could be $0$). This is actually what happens if we let $x=1$ and $y=2$ when $k=1$.

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Answer (score 10):

Here is a collection of [Flawed Induction Proofs](https://brilliant.org/wiki/flawed-induction-proofs/).

Answer (score 7):

**Claim:** For every non-negative integer $n, 5n=0$.

**Base case:** $5\cdot 0=0$.

**Inductive step:** Suppose that $5j=0$ for all non-negative integers $j$ with $0\leq j\leq k$. Write $k+1=i+j$, where $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers less than $k+1$ (I am considering the natural numbers to include $0$). By the induction hypothesis, $5(k+1)=5(i+j)=5i+5j=0+0=0$.

**Flaw:**

> The flaw occurs when going from the base case $n=0$ to the next case, $n=1$. The number $1$ cannot be written as the sum of two smaller natural numbers; thus, we cannot invoke the inductive hypothesis. In the proof, when $k=0$, we cannot write $0+1=i+j$ where $0\leq i\leq 0$ and $0\leq j\leq 0$.

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Answer (score 7):

**Claim:** Given a set of $n$ points. Then these points lay on one line.

**Proof:**

*Inductive Basis*: Clearly, one point lays on one line.

*Inductive Hypothesis:* Given a set of $k$ points. Then these points lay on one line.

*Inductive Step:* Consider a set of $k+1$ points. Consider a subset of $k$ points. Then these lay on a line. Consider another subset of $k$ points. Then these lay on a line. The intersection of these sets contain $k-1$ points, so these lines are clearly the same.

**Flaw:**

> If $k=2$, then the intersection is just a point where multiple lines go through.

Answer (score 6):

For each non-negative integer $n$, let $S(n)$ be the statement $S(n) : n=0.$

**Claim:** Every non-negative integer is equal to $0$.

**Base case:** $S(0)$ is clearly true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 0$ and assume that $S(0),\ldots, S(k)$ are true. To prove that $S(k+1)$ is true, observe that $S(k)$ says $k=0$ and $S(1)$ says $1=0$; hence, we have that $k+1=0+0=0$, proving $S(k+1)$. This concludes the inductive step, and hence the proof by strong induction.

**Flaw:**

> The statement $S(1)$ does not follow from $S(0)$.

Comment: Consider upvoting this comment if this fake proof stumped you for a moment. [Just a simple test to gauge how deceptive this argument really is.]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a double induction 'proof'.

**Claim:** For all integers $n\ge 1$ and $m\ge 0$, $n\mid m$ ($n$ divides $m$).

**Proof:**

Outer induction (on $n$):

**Base case:**  Clearly $1\mid m$ for all $m\ge 0$.

**Inductive step:** Assuming the claim is true for $n=k$, we must show it is true for $n=k+1$.  We do this by strong induction on $m$.

$\hspace{.5in}$ Inner induction (on $m$)

$\hspace{.5in}$ **Base case:** When $m=0$, we need $k+1 \mid 0$, which is clearly true.

$\hspace{.5in}$ **Inductive step:**

$\hspace{.5in}$ Assume that $k+1\mid m$ for $m=0, 1, \dots j$. From this strong induction assumption, we have $k+1\mid 1$ and $k+1 \mid j$.  Hence $k+1$ divides the sum: $k+1\mid j+1$.  So the result holds for $m=j+1$.

By (double) induction, we have $n\mid m$ for all integers $n\ge 1$, $m\ge 0$, as claimed.

**Flaw:**

> On the inner induction you can't go from $m=0$ to $m=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:**

If $a$ is an odd square modulo $m$, then $a$ is a square modulo $2m$.

**Proof:**

Let $m=2^v k$ where $k$ is $m$'s largest odd factor. Proceed by induction on $v$.

**Base case:**

$v=0$, so $m=k$ is odd.

$a$ is a square modulo $k$, so, for some $x$, $k\mid x^2-a$. Modulo $2k$,
\begin{align*}
(k+x)^2 &= k^2+2kx+x^2\\
&= k+x^2\tag{$k^2=k$ as $k$ is odd; $2kx=0$}
\end{align*}
so $x^2$ and $(k+x)^2$ are $a$ and $k+a$ in some order. So $a$ is a square modulo $2k$.

**Inductive step:**

$a$ is a square modulo $2^v k$ so there is an $x$ where $x^2=a\mod 2^v k$.
As the base case is proved, we may suppose that $m$ is even and $v\geqslant1$.
This means that, as $a$ is odd, $x$ is odd.
Knowing that $m$ is even also enables us to refine $x$:
Modulo $m$,
\begin{align*}
(m/2+x)^2 &= (2^{v-1} k+x)^2\\
&= 2^{2v-2} k^2+2\cdot2^{v-1} kx+x^2\\
&=2^{v} kx+x^2\\
&=x^2\\
&=a
\end{align*}
as the other terms are multiples of $m=2^v k$. That is, we may take $0<x<m/2$.

Modulo $2m$,
\begin{align*}
(m/2+x)^2 &= (2^{v-1} k+x)^2\\
&= 2^{2v-2}k^2+2\cdot2^{v-1} kx+x^2\\
&=2^v kx+x^2\\
&=mx+x^2\\
&=m+x^2\tag{as $x$ is odd}
\end{align*}
Thus $x^2$ and $(m/2+x)^2$ are $a$ and $m+a$ in some order. Thus $a$ is a square modulo $2m$. QED.

**Flaw:**

> The base case is valid. The inductive step relies on $2^{v+1}k\mid2^{2v-2}k^2$, which is true only if $2v-2\geqslant v+1$ i.e. $v\geqslant3$ i.e. $8\mid m$.