# Prove that $ j^4+11j^2-12$ is divisible by $3$. $j$ is a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$j$ is a natural number. I know prove $j^4+11j^2-12$ is divisible by $4$, but I realy don't know how to prove, that $j^4+11j^2-12$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove by induction that $n^3 + 11n$ is divisible by $6$ for every positive integer $n$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204306/prove-by-induction-that-n3-11n-is-divisible-by-6-for-every-positive-integ) We have $n^4+11n^2-12=n(n^3+11n)-3\cdot 4$.

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ j\equiv 0\ $ or $\,j\equiv \pm1 $ (so $\,j^2\equiv 1).\,$ In both cases $\,P(j^2)\equiv 0\,$ by $\,P(0)\equiv 0\equiv P(1).\quad $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: You can factor $j^4+11j^2-12 = (j^2+12)(j^2-1) = (j^2+12)(j-1)(j+1)$.

Now, break the proof into $3$ cases:

(1) $j$ is a multiple of $3$

(2) $j$ is one more than a multiple of $3$

(3) $j$ is one less than a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @SimpleArt don't worry, I'll throw my vote into the mix. Perhaps synergy will take hold and together 3 votes will appear?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen :D

Comment: No need of doing cases: $j^4+11j^2-12\equiv j^2(j-1)(j+1)$ and $(j-1)j(j+1)$ is certainly divisible by $3$. +1 anyway.

Comment: ^Of course. I was giving the OP the most straightforward and elementary approach I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

If this looks intimidating to factor, we can look at it $\pmod{3}$ first:
$$j^4+11j^2-12\pmod{3} \equiv j^4-j^2\pmod{3}\equiv j^2(j^2-1) \pmod{3}\equiv j^2(j+1)(j-1)$$
For any number $j$, we have that $j\pmod{3}\in\{0,1,2\}$, so this polynomial will be $0\pmod{3}$.  This means that $3$ divides it.

Answer (score 3):

Write as $j^4+11j^2-12=j^4-j^2 + 12(j^2-1)=j^2(j-1)(j+1)+12(j^2-1)$ then note that the first term contains the product of $3$ consecutive numbers, one of which must be a multiple of $3$, and the second term is a multiple of $12$, thus a multiple of $3\,$.

Answer (score 3):

Look at it mod 3. We have
$$
j^4 + 11j^2 - 12 \equiv j^4 - j^2 \pmod{3}.
$$
For $j \equiv 0, 1, -1 \pmod{3}$, we have $j^2 \equiv j^4 \pmod{3}$, so that
$$
j^4 - j^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using repeated differences and [Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series)  we get
$$
j^4+11j^2-12
=
-12 \binom{j}{0} + 12 \binom{j}{1} + 36 \binom{j}{2} + 36 \binom{j}{3} + 24 \binom{j}{4}
$$
and so $j^4+11j^2-12$ is actually always a mutiple of $12$.

Comment: Original and fine

Answer (score 1):

$j^4+11j^2-12=(j^2+12)(j+1)(j-1)$

1. If $j$ is of the form $3k\implies 3|(j^2+12)$
2. If $j$ is of the form $3k+1\implies 3|(j-1)$
3. If $j$ is of the form $3k+2\implies 3|(j+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following cases:

- $j\equiv0\pmod3 \implies j^4+11j^2-12\equiv0^4+11\cdot0^2-12\equiv0-0-12\equiv0\pmod3$
- $j\equiv1\pmod3 \implies j^4+11j^2-12\equiv1^4+11\cdot1^2-12\equiv1+11-12\equiv0\pmod3$
- $j\equiv2\pmod3 \implies j^4+11j^2-12\equiv2^4+11\cdot2^2-12\equiv16+44-12\equiv0\pmod3$