# Proving $10\cdot n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\geq 0$ using strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

The question says $10\cdot n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n\geq 0$.

Here is my proof by strong induction:

Base case: $10\cdot0=0$.

Let $k\geq 0$, and suppose that for any $m\leq k$ we have that $10\cdot m=0$.

Consider $10\cdot(k+1)$. The number $k+1$ can be written as $m+l$ for some numbers $0\leq m,l\leq k$. By the induction hypothesis, $10\cdot m=0=10\cdot l$.

But then: $10\cdot(k+1)=10\cdot(m+l) = 10\cdot m+10\cdot l=0+0=0$.

Apparently something went wrong in my proof by strong induction, but I cannot seem to figure out what.

Comment: The step from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: There is no base case for strong induction.

Comment: I thought Andre was being a jerk, then I realized....he actually meant from $n=0$ to $n=1$... lol. Thumbs up to Andre : )

Comment: Before proving something, you should probably read the statement to see if it's utter nonsense. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot go like this from $k=0$ to $k=1$ (i.e. $k=1$ cannot be expressed in the form $m+l$ as you wrote).

Comment: Oh thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to sketch out a proof similar to the one you provided, and then I will flesh out why this approach does not work (as an aside, you may find [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196303/fake-induction-proofs) on *fake* induction proofs to be of use in picking up on faulty reasoning sometimes used in induction proofs).

---

**Claim:** For every non-negative integer $n, 10n=0$.

**Base case:** $10\cdot 0=0$.

**Inductive step:** Suppose that $10m=0$ for all non-negative integers $m$ with $0\leq m\leq k$. Write $k+1=\ell+m$, where $\ell$ and $m$ are natural numbers less than $k+1$ (I am considering the natural numbers to include $0$). By the induction hypothesis, $10(k+1)=10(\ell+m)=10\ell+10m=0+0=0$.

---

Can you spot the error truebaran alludes to in his answer? Here it is in more detail:

**Error:** The error lies in going from the base case $n=0$ to the next case, $n=1$. The number $1$ cannot be written as the sum of two smaller natural numbers; thus, we cannot invoke the inductive hypothesis. In the proof, when $k=0$, we cannot write $0+1=\ell+m$ where $0\leq \ell\leq 0$ and $0\leq m\leq 0$.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In general, induction works like this.

Let a statement $\mathcal{S}$ depend on a natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
We write the statement as $\mathcal{S}_n$.

Induction means to proof the following two conditions:

> $$
> \mathcal{S}_0 = \textrm{true} \tag{1}\\
> $$
>   $$
> \mathcal{S}_n = \textrm{true} \Longrightarrow
> \mathcal{S}_{n+1} = \textrm{true}\tag{2}
> $$

whence

> $$
> \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : \mathcal{S}_n = \textrm{true}
> $$

---

Your statement is given by
$$
\mathcal{S}_n =
\langle\textit{For any natural number $n$ holds that $10n=0$.}\rangle
$$

The second part of induction (2) would imply that
$$
\mathcal{S}_n = \textrm{true} \Longrightarrow
\mathcal{S}_{n+1} = \textrm{false}
$$
Whence induction has failed.

After all we have IF $10n = 0$ THEN $10(n+1)=0$, thus $10=0$ which is false.